# Problems in producing animation GIF files in R

Tags: visualisation, animation, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a GIF file for my maps in R using `gganimate` but errors show up.

```
devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate")

library(ggplot2)
data(sp6, package = 'aqp')
p <- ggplot(sp6, aes(x = pH, frame = hz)) +geom_density() 
library(gganimate)
```

`Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database 'C:/R/R-3.4.2/library/gganimate/help/gganimate.rdb' is corrupt`

(I think this can be fixed by restart R session? Anyway, the real problem below ...)

```
gganimate(p)
```

`Executing: 
"C:\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0 -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png
    Rplot4.png "file148c3014687f.gif""
'C:\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
an error occurred in the conversion... see Notes in ?im.convert
Error in file(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe" --version' had status 1 
2: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png "file148c3014687f.gif""' had status 1 
3: In cmd.fun(convert) :
  '"C:\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png "file148c3014687f.gif""' execution failed with error code 1
4: running command '"C:\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png "file148c3014687f.gif""' had status 127 
5: In file(file, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\gjiang\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpA95rFH/gganimate\file148c3014687f.gif': No such file or directory`

Is there a way to fix this?

P.S

After installing the software ImageMagick 7.0.7, I used `p <- animate(ras.stack)` in the `raster` package and then used `saveGIF(p)` in the `animation` package, but still getting

`'C:\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: ImageMagick is a stand alone application and not an R package. The animate package uses it to build gifs. You need go to the relevant website, download and install the software.

Comment: I downloaded and installed ImageMagick 7.0.7, then reinstalled gganimate in R again, but still getting error: `'C:\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`.  Does ImageMagick have to be installed under a certain path? @JeffreyEvans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a documented issue in gganimate. The animate packages deals with some of the known issues but gganimate is a bit behind on addressing changes in ImageMagick. Two potential workarounds are:

Running an installation directly in R using installr.

```
library(installr)
install.ImageMagick()
```

Or, setting a windows environment variable from R.

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick/bin",
Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep = ";"))
```

Although, it looks like the new version of ImageMagick does not distribute the "convert.exe" executable. The portable install does, however, contain the "convert.exe". All you have to do is create an ImageMagick directory and uncompress the zip file to it. The "convert.exe" executable is then contained in root and not bin, which becomes relevant if you have to explicitly set the path. If you put the directory under "C:/" the path would look like this:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/ImageMagick", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep = ";"))
```

You can grab the portable install at: ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-7.0.7-8-portable-Q16-x64.zip

Comment: `install.ImageMagick(URL = "http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php")` shows `Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection`. The portable install works perfect. Thanks a lot @Jeffrey Evans